# Get value of all dynamically created hidden fields with class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the values of dynamically created hidden fields with a class reference.

Example of created hidden field

```
<input class="SelectedClaimants" id="CodesList_2__Claimant" name="CodesList[2].Claimant" type="hidden" value="Jason Statham">
```

This is something along the lines of what i have tried.

```
$('.listSelected').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function (event) {

    $(".SelectedClaimants").find('input[type=hidden]').each(function () {
        var testC += $(this).val();
    });
});
```

I was aiming to have them create into an array object, but at the moment i am happy just to get the values out into a concatenated string.

Comment: `$('.SelectedClaimants input[type="hidden"]').map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');`

Comment: @Tushar watch it, the input has class (not an input inside some element).

Comment: @Tushar i just get a empty string returned. I don't think '.SelectedClaimants input[type="hidden"]' is finding my hidden fields. inspecting the element i can see the hidden fields have values.

Comment: @Pomster, Just correcting Tushar, `$('.SelectedClaimantsinput[type="hidden"]').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get().join(',');`

Comment: 'input[type="hidden"].SelectedClaimants' seem's to pick something up.

Comment: @Pomster, Probably _something_ you are expecting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5g5dtcpt/) (the result is logged to the console). It's based onn Tushar's answer, but the selector was wrong.

```
$('input[type="hidden"].SelectedClaimants').map(function () { 
    return $(this).val(); 
}).get().join(',')
```

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis, and probably a `.get()` at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()`, spread element, `for..of` loop. Note, `id`, e.g., `CodesList_2__Claimant` should be unique in `document`.

```
var testC = [];

for (let el of [...document.querySelectorAll("input[type='hidden'].SelectedClaimants")]) {
  testC.push(el.value)
}
```